# Create expandable list with image saved in sdcard

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I would like your help for the following, how do I create a custom expandable list and put each of them an image that saved in sdcard, I have a database with the path to each image.

```
cursor = builder.query(
            /* from */ Usuario.getInstance().getReadableDatabase( ),
            /* select */ columnsToReturn,
            /* where */ Usuario.CPF_KEY + " = \'" + LastLoginData.getCpf( ) + "\'",
            null, null, null, 
            /* order by */ Usuario.REG_ID_KEY + " ASC" );

    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorTreeAdapter(
        this, cursor, R.layout.registro_parent,
        new String[] { Usuario.REG_DATE_KEY, Usuario.REG_TYPE_KEY, Usuario.REG_STATUS_KEY },
        new int[] { R.id.textData, R.id.textRegTipo, R.id.textStatus },
        R.layout.registro_child,
        new String[] { Usuario.REG_MEDIA_THUMB_KEY, Usuario.REG_INFO_KEY },
        new int[] {R.id.imgSnapshot2 , R.id.textComentarios } ) 
    {
        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor( Cursor cursor ) {

            String id = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( Usuario.REG_ID_KEY ) );
            SQLiteDatabase db = Usuario.getInstance().getWritableDatabase( );

            String query = "select " + Usuario.REG_ID_KEY + ", " + Usuario.REG_MEDIA_THUMB_KEY + ", " + Usuario.REG_INFO_KEY + " from " + Usuario.REG_TABLE + " where " + Usuario.REG_ID_KEY + "='" + id + "'";
            Cursor cur = db.rawQuery( query, null );

            return cur;
        }

        @Override
        protected void bindGroupView( View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded ) {
            super.bindGroupView( view, context, cursor, isExpanded );

            ImageView img = ( ImageView )view.findViewById( R.id.imageExpand );
            if( img != null ) {
                if( isExpanded ) {
                    img.setImageResource( R.drawable.btn_circulo_baixo );
                }
                else {
                    img.setImageResource( R.drawable.btn_circulo_dir );
                }
            }

            TextView status = ( TextView )view.findViewById( R.id.textStatus );
            if( status != null ) {
                String s = status.getText().toString();
                if( s.equals( getString( R.string.Enviada ) ) ) {
                    status.setTextColor( 0xffff0000 );
                }
                else if( s.equals( getString( R.string.EmAndamento ) ) ) {
                    status.setTextColor( 0xffffcc00 );
                }
                else if( s.equals( getString( R.string.Atendida ) ) ) {
                    status.setTextColor( 0xff00cc00 );
                }
                else {
                    status.setTextColor( 0xff808080 );
                }
            }

            if( isExpanded ) {
                img = ( ImageView )view.findViewById( R.id.imageRodape );

                if( img != null ) {
                    img.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
                }
            }
            else {
                img = ( ImageView )view.findViewById( R.id.imageRodape );
                if( img != null ) {
                    img.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                }
            }
        }
    };

    listView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
```

This code inserts everything right but not the picture: (can someone help ^ ^ 
Thanks guys ^ ^

an example of how to make expandable now would be a help if it's otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for Expandable listview .

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/